# Jquery serialize() error in inputs with extra property

Tags: jquery, serialization

```
<form id="lol" method="post" action="?" zidprofile="210" zmarked="true"  referer="http://yahoo.com/">
   <input type="text" name="age" value="22" />
   <input type="text" name="name" value="Jhon" ztarget="415" />
   <input type="text" name="mail" value="test@gmail.com" zcodeg="inner" />
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When form submited print this:

```
Array (
  [age] => 22,
  [name] => Jhon,
  [mail] => test@gmail.com
)
```

But Jquery and serialize return only:

```
alert($('#lol').serialize()); // age=22
```

And:

```
$('input[zcodeg="inner"]').each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Work!, alert: "mail"

What happen?

Comment: Please show your call to `serialize()`.

Comment: alert($('#lol').serialize()); // age=22

Comment: maybe serialize() dont like your custom attributes of the input elements?

Comment: then take it out and test it without your custom attributes !?!?

Comment: without custom attributes works.

Comment: how do I work with custom attributes?

Comment: Worksforme http://jsfiddle.net/dmethvin/fbX3g/

Comment: mmm yes, work but my web dont work :-s, alert(ob.serialize()); alert(ob.find('input').length) return age=22
 and "3" :-s not happening, if remove attribute of input with firebug return a normal serialize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems serialize() does not support custom attributes in input fields however... take them out and use common attributes like `rel=""` or if your using HTML5 you may wanna use the `data-` attribute. maybe it works with this attributes

Comment: need more attributes, 5 extra attributes aprox for each input. I use html5 but visitors use ie8.

Comment: @user1243068 what's using IE8 got to do with your use of, and this problem with custom attributes? HTML is a mark-up language, IE is a browser...

Comment: as you using HTML 5 its no problem to use data-yxz attributes... for no browser... and maybe serialize() accepting them more then invalid attributes

Comment: The problem is that before submitting the form apply all inputs are disabled:

    $ (formOb.find('input').each(function(){
       $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });

jquery not process inputs disabled :)

Sorry and thanks.